# question erroneously closed as duplicate

Tags: discussion

Please reopen the front page question about ["any doubt" vs. "any doubts."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14428/any-further-doubts-or-any-further-doubt) It is closed as duplicate with a link to a question that is not the same.

Comment: I think I agree with you on this, but as Matt closed the question I'd like to speak with him about it before singlehandedly reversing his action. (Of course, if the question gets 5 reopen votes in the meantime, that would take care of it too :). But I hesitate to use mod-powers to reverse mod-powers without discussing it first!)

Answer (score 3):

On first reading, it appeared that the question was a duplicate of a question asking about how to pluralize *doubt*, but on second reading I think it's more about how to pluralize a word after *any* in a more general sense.

That's make the question still a duplicate; it just makes it a duplicate of [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/singular-or-plural-after-any) instead.

Comment: The question has been reopened now, so I can't tell which earlier question it was closed against. I think the later question seems to be asking about whether one can validly use singular or plural after *any* (rather than any possible distinction between having *doubt* or *doubts*). So even though I don't agree that it's *more about how to pluralize a word after **any***, I do agree it's a duplicate of [Singular or plural after “any”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You can see which question it was closed against if you check the [revision history](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/14428/revisions) (which is admittedly hard to do, since there's no link to it, or there wasn't until now).